# how can i access a directory from network in apache using httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, documentroot

I want apache to access a location which is in network that means instead of specifying a DocumentRoot from withing the server(mine is centos) i want the apache to access a directory which is on diffrent machine in my case it is a windows machine. I have a Static Ip 202.189.*.206 from where the network in being passed to the intranet now i want to keep the keep my files in a directory which is not on the centos server but on a different machine which is a windows machine

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: mount the remote directory to a location on your server.

Step 2: interact with that folder as if it were local.

There is no step 3. :)

Comment: Is there any way i can do this without mounting the drive ?

Comment: No, you need to mount the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

I find the Apache documentation to be an excellent source of information - you should try looking at it.

In particular for [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) it says

> [Syntax](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax):  DocumentRoot directory-path

Note also the link provided in the documentation to [Syntax](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) it contains valuable information too ...

> directory-path
>       The path to a directory in the local file-system beginning with the root directory as in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/path/to/.

So there is all the information you need. DocumentRoot should be a directory-path, a directory-path should be in the local file-system.

You will need to bring the remote directory into your local filesystem.

Comment: I have been continuously trying this what is mentioned on this page but i am unbale to access a directory which is not on the server

Comment: @user216476: You have to mount the remote directory into the local filesystem is the answer to your question above anything else is a different problem you need to solve.